# Does a VGA to DVI adapter increase the max refresh rate of monitors?

Tags: display

Will a VGA to DVI adapter increase the max refresh rate of the monitor? (I'm guessing it won't because its just an adapter after all). The maximum refresh rate of VGA ports is 60 Hz while that of DVI port is up to 144 Hz

I found the Samsung SR350 monitor but oddly it still uses the old VGA port which even modern graphics cards don't have anymore
See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwrmT46B3_g

The reviewer makes a very good point. Why put a VGA port for a monitor that's rated to be 75 Hz. So its thereby also conclusive that VGA LED monitors are to be avoided? I am seeing a lot of monitors that come in either HDMI or VGA instead of HDMI or DVI...

Comment: The SR350 has an HDMI port as well, so it will do 75Hz over HDMI. The VGA port is for backwards compatibility.

Comment: You may want to read up on differences between DVI-A, DVI-D and DVI-I too.

Answer (score 0):

> The maximum refresh rate of VGA ports is 60 Hz while that of DVI port is up to 144 Hz

That means you have a digital monitor, which has an A/D converter and digitizer on the VGA input, and this digitizer can handle 60 Hz max for some reason (if that's what your datasheet says, usually this is resolution dependent).

DVI comes in two flavours, analog and digital. You didn't say, but I strongly assume it's the **digital** DVI input that can have 144 Hz (again, that should be resolution dependent, because usually it's the data rate that is limited).

So if you can find an **external** analog VGA to digital DVI converter which handles 144 Hz at the desired resolution, you can "increase the max refresh rate" (if you want to phrase it that way).

A passive analog VGA to analog DVI-A converter is not going to help you in that situation.

> So its thereby also conclusive that VGA LED monitors are to be avoided?

It is conclusive that you cannot make any blanket statements without looking at the details.

First, the refresh rate of the input may or may not coincide with the actual refresh rate of the image; digital monitors to lots of conversion there.

Second, there's no reason not to put an VGA-to-DVI converter with a higher max refresh rate in the monitor, other than cost and that more than 75 Hz on VGA was really really rare. So it depends on the actual monitor.

If you want a blanket statement:

If you have a digital monitor (and all modern monitors are digital), just **use a digital data source**. Converting your framebuffer to analog VGA and back to digital will loose quality, no matter what you do. Doing that makes no sense.

Comment: What you’re saying is mostly correct, but VGA outputs would also have to support these modes. They generally don’t, due to bandwidth constraints.

Comment: @DanielB the bandwidth constraint is mostly on the pixel clock (and on old analog monitors, indeed on the horizontal and vertical frequency, because those also use analog circuitry). So I could program you most video cards with a real small resolution with a high vertical refresh rate. (Try this out, it's easy under Linux; X modelines are fun). For digital-analog and analog-digital converters, horizontal and vertical refresh are mostly an artifact, and if they are constrained, then by the number of available bits in the corresponding counter registers.